# Scrabble like board games are they on-topic?

Tags: discussion, top-7, on-topic

It has a totally different mechanics but still a board game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I think we should allow these.

The world in general admits to an interpretation of "boardgame" that definitely encompasses those games.